# How to filter/sniff out web pages according to data(text) contained?

Tags: proxy, firewall, scapy

I am looking for information useful for my little project that allows me to sniff web page received from a web server and before it appear in the browser I will test the content (text),then according to this test,my program blocks(or redirects) the page in case the test is false...

I found a very complete library is [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html), he can sniff and forge all the traffic including http replies..

[I found someone looking to do similar things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773093/python-intercept-web-traffic-from-browser) , but the response suggested to develop a proxy..

my question is: Is what it takes make a proxy? or just scapy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty,

To answer your question yes you can do this with scapy but essentially you will be creating a proxy in the process.

As a matter of fact your request is practically the definition of a web proxy server.

dc

Comment: Thank you dc , I see why a proxy is essential, but I have a concern about the configuration in the browser (proxy configuration) I would like this to be automatic (no configuration at the customer's browser),I already know a proxy that works without configuration in the browser....

Comment: have you any idea how to do this under Windows ?

Comment: Well in scapy do something like this.. set proxy in web browser to scapy box ip port 8080 then on the scapy box sniff(filter="port 8080") then "Do something to pkt" then send("processedpkt")

Comment: sorry re-read this, I know there are ways to set proxy through group policy and other ways to hack around and get a system to use you as a proxy as well, however there is no other way that I know of besides being the gateway on a lan segment to automatically  make users push a service through a remote system.

Comment: Welcome back dc, I have posted a detailed question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284846/how-to-force-all-browsers-to-pass-by-proxy#comment13231328_10284846