# How to force All Browsers to pass by Proxy?

Tags: redirect, proxy

My question is bit similar to [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/29701/global-proxy-settings-for-windows)

However, I'm looking to do this programmatically... for security reasons my proxy must operate without any prior configuration in the browser (proxy settings ..).
in other words , force all http request (browsers )to pass by my proxy, without any configuration, because it's easiest to delete the proxy settings by the user...

there is any tricks to do that ?

Comment: There is no "programmatic" answer to that.  You have to either control the desktops or an up-level gateway.

Comment: there is any suggestion to start  from there?

Comment: i need to redirect the destination address and port(for each Http request) to localhost and 8080 ...

Comment: As I stated earlier, is this a windows domain perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a windows domain use group policy to manage proxy settings.

If you are trying to do this subversively you may way to read this

http://perimetergrid.com/wp/2008/01/11/wpad-internet-explorers-worst-feature/

Gotta love WPAD!

I hope it helps,

dc