# Python-how to get the http request URL sent by local machine?

Tags: python, sockets, http, filter, request

I want to get the **http** and **https** URL sent by **local machine**.
So, I can do something on the URL.
Just like get all the image URL, then download the big image into a specify folder.

Would you give me some advice?Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: install `squid` proxy on localhost, then start playing with `url rewriting`

Comment: can you give us an example to clarify your intention?

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani I want to write a program and enjoy it.So I don't want to  use this,but thank u all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some quick research around this and found another [SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773093/python-intercept-web-traffic-from-browser) that would help you.

Basically, it shows using the usage of the [WebOb Framework](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/do-it-yourself.html) and the [Paste Framework](http://pythonpaste.org/) that can be used to create HTTP Middleware to intercept requests.

Hope, this gets you going on a way to solve the problem you are currently pondering over